# Installing Windows 7 drivers automatically

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Is there any simple and free method to install all hardware drivers at once and keep them up-to-date?

Windows Update isn't the choice. It didn't find all hardware drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you [DriverPack Solutions](http://drpsu.com/index.htm).
It's a powerful, free and all-in-one pack of drivers in one ~3GB DVD ISO.
It always has the latest drivers, and it **automatically** finds and install drivers for **almost all** devices.
Also you can use its ~7MB program, which will find and download your drivers from it's base.

Comment: How many PC's have you used this on, and what were the results?

Comment: @Moab ,I've used it for many-many PCs, and they all work fine after it

Comment: wow this looks useful. how can we be sure that the software is clean?

Comment: I've checked it many many times with latest bases of Kaspersky Internet Securities. It's clean.

Comment: @SEARAS Chrome flags the lite download ans malicious, lol

Comment: @Moab, it just suspects, it doesn't check. Have you checked it with normal antivirus?

Comment: @SEARAS MSE has no issues with it, just chrome. false positive most likely

Comment: @Moab , it's ok