# How do i tell if my drivers are up to date on Acer?

Tags: drivers

My computer crashed with a blue screen the other day after trying to load sandboxie. For this reason, I think it is conflicting with something. I checked that the drivers of my Acer Aspire One AOD270 were up to date on [this intel based site](http://www.drivermanager.com/en/down...tel&Logo=intel). The site suggests updates for two drivers.

- Intel NM10 Express Chipset
- Realtek PCIE Card reader.

I am confused as to where to download the drivers. Should I prefer the Intel Driver update site or the Acer drivers download page? I bought the laptop here in SE Asia about a year ago. The ''HOT!! NEW download tool'' on the [Acer drivers site](http://support.acer.com/us/en/produc...1&modelId=4040) does not seem to work and the info about removing and installing drivers is limited. Not sure what to trust on non Acer / manufacturer sites.

---

To analyze the blue screen, I ran Bluescreenview on the dump file and it is showing;

```
''caused by driver'' igdkmd32.sys
''file description'' Intel (R) WDDM Kernel mode driver
''product name''Intel Graphics Accelerator Drivers for Windows 7(R)
```

I have located the igdkmd32.sys file inside INTEL GRAPHICS MEDIA ACCELERATOR 3600 SERIES 8.14.8.1064. When I click on `update driver` in control panel it searches and says its up to date. In windows maintenance it says this Intel had a problem, but no solution.

For all I know my drivers could be up to date and the issue lies elsewhere. Can anybody provide advice in the form of a step by step process that a rookie could follow? I have never done this before.

That is, do I delete the old driver first and then download the new one. How much of a problem could I cause by downloading incorrect drivers? As of yet, I have not downloaded any drivers. I have asked on other forums with no luck.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Some general suggestions:

- avoid "drivers update" sites (verify that they can be trusted)
- do not bother with `update driver` in the control panel
- let the OS handle old drivers (just install the new ones)
- product (laptop) manufacturer's drivers are preferable to drivers from the Chipset maker
- wrong drivers are harmless (unless they are malware) because the OS will reject them.
- wrong driver for the graphics adapter are easier to install and will cause poor performance

A comment on your attempted approach:

Although I can see how the message from the BSOD dump would make you think that it is a good Idea to update the driver, doing so rarely helps. Of course, this is based on personal experience and numerous sources will have you think otherwise. In general, it is "the first thing to try" and therefore I will not advice against it.

After you have downloaded the latest drivers for your laptop from the Acer support site, I suggest you start looking for clues about what could be wrong with the combination of application + sandbox.

If manually checking the for the latest drivers on a website is not your cup of tea, then there are alternatives. For example: [Installing Windows 7 drivers automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/499013/installing-windows-7-drivers-automatically) . This is not exactly what you are looking for, but similar questions have been asked ans answered on this website.

---

Your aim is presumably to run an application in a sandbox, but you have not mentioned the application even once. This is counterproductive towards your ultimate goal ([read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Do keep in mind that Superuser is not a support forum, and that precise questions which can be answered with one block of text are preferred on this questions-answers website.